# Cannot connect to Microsoft Azure from shinyapps.io

Tags: r, azure, shiny, odbc, shinyapps

I built an Rshiny application that pulls data from Microsoft Azure. My application works locally when I use the 'SQL Server' driver in my connection string, but does not work when I publish the app on shinyapps.io. 
Based on a suggestion from [here](https://itsalocke.com/blog/connecting-to-sql-server-on-shinyapps.io/), I have been trying to use the 'FreeTDS' driver to connect with Azure when publishing on shinyapps.io but I am not having any luck.

Here is my connection string:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 Driver = "FreeTDS",
                 Server = "servername", 
                 Database = "databasename",
                 Uid = "uid",
                 Pwd = "pwd",
                 Port = 1433,
                 TDS_Version = 9.0)
```

I receive the following error message when using the 'FreeTDS' driver:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 08001: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
```

I have tried using TDS_Version 7.0, 7.2, 7.4, 9.0 - none have worked. Can anyone help me decode this error message? Thank you!

Note: I am working with R 3.6 on Windows 10. I have whitelisted shinyapps.io IP addresses on Azure, so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For connecting both on local Windows and Shinyapps.io, this has worked for me:

```
library(RODBC)

is_local<-Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT')==""

dbConnector <- function(local=FALSE){
    if(local){dbConn <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;Server=xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xxxxxxxxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxxxxxxx;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30")
        } else {dbConn <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=FreeTDS;TDS_Version=8.0;Server=xxxx.database.windows.net; Port=1433;Database=xxxxx;Uid=xxxxxx;Pwd=xxxxxxxxx;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30")}
}
dbConn <- dbConnector(is_local)
```

Comment: Thanks Darren. You're getting a successful connection between shinyapps.io and Microsoft Azure?

Comment: Yes, this is consistently working fine. Remember you need to white list the IP addresses of shinyapps.io 54.204.34.9
54.204.36.75
54.204.37.78
34.203.76.245
3.217.214.132
34.197.152.155

Answer (score 0):

The driver requires DSN and PWD to be specified only on the connection string, they cannot be specified in the DSN. http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm

For more details, refer Similar [GitHub](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/170) issue, which addresses similar issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for you response. Do you know of documentation that provides a step by step tutorial in plain English on how to install FreeTDS to windows 10 (preinstalled with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)? Sorry to need a bit more hand-holding, this is all new to me, and unfortunately I do not understand your answer.

Comment: From the many posts on the internet it seems that FreeTDS as used with Shinyapps.io is not working with Azure SQL. Probably to make you pay $$$ for their commercial driver packages.

Comment: You may try the steps mentioned in the article: https://medium.com/@kelly.obriant/tinkering-with-azure-sql-databases-and-shinyapps-io-c08567e0d4f2