# Cannot Connect to Azure SQL when deploying to Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, shiny, odbc

I have built an R shiny app/dashboard which runs perfectly on my local Windows 10 machine. I am now ready to deploy it to the web. I have chosen to do this using Shinapps.io. The app deploys, but immediately disconnects when trying to access it. Checking the log file yields this error:

> Error : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable
> to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
> [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source  [FreeTDS][SQL
> Server]Unknown host machine name.

My current implementation for connecting to the database is as follows:

```
conn_args <- config::get("dataconnection")

is_local<-Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT')==""
message(paste("is_local: ", is_local))

if(is_local){
    con <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                           Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                           Server = conn_args$server,
                           Database = conn_args$database,
                           Uid = conn_args$uid,
                           PWD = conn_args$pwd,
                           Port = conn_args$port,
                           TrustServerCertificate="no")
} else {
    #con <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("Driver=FreeTDS;TDS_Version=7.2;Server=tcp:#######;Port=1433;Database=######;Uid=######;Pwd=#######;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30")
    #con <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("Driver=FreeTDS;TDS_Version-7.2;Server=tcp:#######,1433;Database=###########;Uid=######;Pwd=######;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;")

    con <- odbc::dbConnect(
                odbc::odbc(),
                Driver = "FreeTDS",
                Server = conn_args$server,
                Database = conn_args$database,
                UID = conn_args$uid,
                PWD = conn_args$pwd,
                Port = 1433,
                TrustServerCertificate="no",
                TDS_Version = 7.4
    )    
}
```

As ShinyApps.io runs a Linux instance, I'm using FreeTDS as the driver on deployment. I have adjusted the TDS_Version with 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.4, 8.0, and 9.0, as well as removing that parameter completely. Initally I tried using "SQLServer" as the driver name as per the Shinyapps.io documentation suggestion but that failed, too. I even tried using the `RODBC` package instead of `odbc`, but that went nowhere either.

I have set my Azure firewall to let in all necessary IP addresses. I even briefly opened the firewall completely, but that did not yield different results.

I have checked every thread and tutorial I can find, including:

- [Cannot connect to Microsoft Azure from shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486557/cannot-connect-to-microsoft-azure-from-shinyapps-io)
- [Connecting Azure SQL databse to shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045106/connecting-azure-sql-databse-to-shinyapps-io)
- https://groups.google.com/g/shinyapps-users/c/hs4bQHsk9JU
- https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html#accessing-databases-with-odbc

Besides the arguments passed to the driver parameter(s), my connection arguments remain the same for local and web deployment. What am I missing? Is Azure SQL simply not compatible with Shinyapps.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database-in-shinyapps-io/45723

In the Azure portal, the ODBC connection string formats the server name like so: Server=tcp:servername.database.windows.net

Although this works locally, shinyapps.io does not like that format. I simply had to remove "tcp:" prefix from the server name, and the connection went through: Server=servername.database.windows.net

I also changed my driver to "SQLServer", although "FreeTDS" is still a viable option. If you use "FreeTDS", ensure that you have this extra parameter: TDS_Version=7.2

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.